# Moment generating function and expected value of $Y=\left|X-2\right|$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, moment-generating-functions

Random variable of probability density function of X is

${f}_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{2},0\le x\le 1\phantom{\rule{0ex}{0ex}} $

${f}_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{4},3\le x\le 5$

Find moment generating function ${M}_{Y}(t)$ of $Y=\left|X-2\right|$ and from here find $E(Y)$.

**Here is my solution:** ${M}_{Y}(t)=E\left[{e}^{tY}\right]=E\left[{e}^{t\left|X-2\right|}\right]=\int _{0}^{1}\frac{1}{2}{e}^{t(x-2)}dx+\int _{3}^{5}\frac{1}{4}{e}^{t(x-2)}dx=\frac{1}{4t}(2{e}^{-t}-2{e}^{-2t}+{e}^{3t}-{e}^{t})$

I want to use formula $E\left[Y\right]=\frac{d({M}_{Y}(t))}{dt}(t=0)$ to find expected value $E\left[Y\right]$ , but ${M}_{Y}(t)$ will be undefined when  $t=0$.

How can I calculate that? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I tried to edit and make minor typesetting changes, but apparently I messed up! I’m sure you will get the idea and fix it yourself. :)

Comment: I am not good at this :(

Comment: No worries. First I got confused, then I realized the pdf is piece-wise. Then I tried using *cases* to make it more legible and I messed up myself!

Comment: In the first integral, shouldn’t it be $e^{t(2-x)}$?

Comment: Oh I see, this time I messed up!

Answer (score 1):

Your formula for the MGF is valid only for $t \neq 0$. For $t=0$ we have $M_Y(t)=Ee^{0X}=e^{0}=1$. With this value at $0$ $M_Y$ is actually continuous and even continuously differentiable at $0$.

Now $M_Y'(t)=\frac {(4t)(-2e^{-t}+4e^{-2t}+3e^{3t}-e^{t})-4 (2e^{-t}-2e^{-2t}+e^{3t}-e^{t})} {16t^{2}}$ and $M_Y'(0)$ is the limiting value of this at $0$. Using the fact that $e^{ct}\sim 1+ct+c^{2}t^{2}/2$ for $t$ near $0$ you can compute this limit.

Comment: I do not understand clearly sorry

Comment: Can I use L'Hospital Rule for that?

Comment: @softglance By definition $M_Y(0)=Ee^{0Y}=1$. Why is this undefined? Your calculation of $M_Y(t)$ is valid only when $t \neq 0$ and you should not try to put $t=0$ in that expression.

Comment: @softglance Yes, L'Hopital's Rule can be used  but series expansion of the exponential function makes the calculation simpler.

Comment: okay thank you sir